# Angular 2 test cannot load custom package

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, angular, typescript

I am following the offical angular2 guide for testing on an existing project.

I use a custom libary, [downloadjs](http://danml.com/download.html) which works just fine when I run the application. But I get an error in the console in case of test running:

```
"__zone_symbol__zoneAwareStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/downloadjs/download.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/downloadjs/download.js\n\tError loading node_modules/downloadjs/download.js as \"downloadjs\" from app/utilities/file-handler.utility.js"
```

I used `npm install downloadjs` to get the tool.

file-handler.utility.js is the following:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import downloadjs=require("downloadjs");
@Injectable()
export class FileHandler{

  public static download(fileToDownload: any) {
    downloadjs(fileToDownload, "filename.txt" ,"text/plain");
  }   
}
```

I have created a defs.spec.ts file in the same folder:

```
declare module 'downloadjs'{
    function download(data:any, strFileName:string, strMimeType:string):void;

        export = download;
}
```

and added the path to systemjs.config.js:

```
 // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'downloadjs': 'npm:downloadjs/download.js'
```

So this runs just fine with `npm start.`

But as the guide states, after creating 1st.spec.ts with this:

```
describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

this throws the error I pasted on the top. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you're installing manually with npm have you tried installing the library globally: npm install -g downloadjs

Comment: tried it, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to defs.spec.ts location. We decided to use an existing angular 2 template, and after integrating with it, the tests works now.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by "angular 2 template"? Will you please add working code so it will be helpful for who wants to use downloadjs in angular 2 app.

Comment: we moved the entire project into a new skeleton, called [Azimuth template](https://themeforest.net/item/azimuth-angular-2-admin-template/19182105). Nowdays, I use Angular CLI to create projects, and this problem has not occured since then (we use Angular 5 now)